# Drawing an interval with PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I am trying to draw some intervals with PSTricks. I found some LaTeX code but I don't know how to edit it to get what I want.

I would like to draw the x-axis line with the interval in red but I don't want to have any graduation and I would like to write a and b under each extremity of my interval.

Here is the code that I have.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=0.5cm, yunit=0.5cm, yAxis=false}   %scales the picture, removes the y-axis
\begin{pspicture}(-11,0)(11,0)  
\psaxes[Dx=5, subticks=5]{->}(0,0)(-11,0)(11,0) %creates axes
\psline[linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red]{[-]}(-2,0)(5,0)   %creates a thick, red line from -2 (closed) to 5 (closed)
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, is it possible to compile the document directly ? I mean, I use texmaker and with PST I have to compile with XeLatex then show the pdf, and I would like to show the pdf directly.

Thank you for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edited Version

#### Adaptations

- inserted magic comment: `%!TeX program = xelatex` to tell the editor what it should use
- replaced `\psaxes` by `\psline{->}` to just draw an arrow
- added text a, b with `\rput`

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
%!TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=0.5cm, yunit=0.5cm} %scales the picture
\begin{pspicture}(-11,0)(11,0)
    \psline{->}(-11,0)(11,0)
    \psline[linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red]{[-]}(-2,0)(5,0) %creates a thick, red line from -2 (closed) to 5 (closed)
    \rput(-2,-1){$a$}
    \rput(5,-1){$b$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Original Version

#### Adaptations

- inserted magic comment: `%!TeX program = xelatex` to tell the editor what it should use
- changed `{[-]}` to `{-}` at the `\psline` command to remove graduation
- added text a, b with `\rput`

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
%!TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=0.5cm, yunit=0.5cm, yAxis=false}   %scales the picture, removes the y-axis
\begin{pspicture}(-11,0)(11,0)  
    \psaxes[Dx=5, subticks=5]{->}(0,0)(-11,0)(11,0) %creates axes
    \psline[linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red]{-}(-2,0)(5,0)   %creates a thick, red line from -2 (closed) to 5 (closed)
    \rput(-2,.6){$a$}
    \rput(5,.6){$b$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot !
I am sorry I mistranslated, by graduation I meant the little lines and the numbers 0, 5, 10... In fact, I would like to draw an arrow with a generic interval.

Comment: @Emilie I made an edit to my answer. As these seem to be some basic `pstricks` commands, it might be useful to have a look at some starting guide or the introduction of the corresponding documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same result with two lines of Tikz code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-latex] (-4.2,0) -- (7.2,0) node[below right]{$x$};
%       \foreach \i in {-4,...,7}
%       \draw[line width=.5,] (\i,.15)--(\i,-.15);
%       \foreach \i in {-4,-2,...,7}
%       \draw[line width=.5,] (\i,.15)--(\i,-.15) node[below] {\small $\i$};
        \draw[red,line width=4] (-2,0) node[above] {$a$}--(4,0) node[above] {$b$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If You decomment the four central lines You have this output (with some scaling):

[image]